# Rewriting scala code in object-oriented style style to reduce repetitive use of similar functions

Tags: object-oriented, scala, apache-spark

I need help in rewriting my code to be less repetitive. I am used to coding procedural and not object-oriented. My scala program is for Databricks.

how would you combine cmd 3 and 5 together? Does this involve using polymorphism? My notebook first import parquet staging files in parallel. Then it run notebooks in parallel. I am repeating my parallel function, tryNotebookRun, twice, but for different scenarios.

````
////cmd 1
// Set Environment
var client = "client"
var storageAccount = "storageaccount"
var container = client + "-dl"
// Connect to Azure DataLake
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key." + storageAccount + ".dfs.core.windows.net",
  dbutils.secrets.get(scope = storageAccount, key = storageAccount)
  )
// Set database
spark.sql("USE " + client)

////cmd 2
//import needed packages
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.{Future, blocking, Await}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.util.control.NonFatal
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import com.databricks.WorkflowException
import collection.mutable._
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

////cmd 3
///this part set up functions and class for importing stg parquet files as spark tables in parallel
// the next two functions are for retry purpose. if running a process fail, it will retry
def tryRun (path: String, schema: String, table: String): Try[Any] = {
  Try{
    dbutils.fs.rm(s"dbfs:/user/hive/warehouse/$client.db/$schema$table", true)
    spark.sql(s"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $schema$table")
    var df = sqlContext.read.parquet(s"$path/$schema$table/*.parquet")
    df.write.saveAsTable(schema + table)
  }
}
def runWithRetry(path: String, schema: String, table: String, maxRetries: Int = 3) = {
  var numRetries = 0
  while (numRetries < maxRetries){
    tryRun(path, schema, table) match {
      case Success(_) => numRetries = maxRetries
      case Failure(_) => numRetries = numRetries + 1
    }
  }
}
case class tableInfo(path: String, schema: String, table: String)
def parallelRuns(tableList: scala.collection.mutable.MutableList[tableInfo]): Future[Seq[Any]] = {
  val numRunsInParallel = 5
  // If you create too many notebooks in parallel the driver may crash when you submit all of the jobs at once.
  // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numRunsInParallel))
  Future.sequence(
    tableList.map { item =>
      Future {
        runWithRetry(item.path, item.schema, item.table)
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
      }
    }
  )
}

////cmd 4
///Load STG data in the format of Parquet files from Data Lake to Databrick
//Variables
val schema = "STG"
val dataFolder = List(schema)
var tableCollection = MutableList[tableInfo]()
//List of data to be added
val tableList = List(
 "AdverseEvents",
 "Allergies"
)

for (table <- tableList){
  for (folder <- dataFolder){
    var path = s"abfss://$container@$storageAccount.dfs.core.windows.net/$folder"
    var a = tableInfo(path, schema, table)
    tableCollection += a
  }
}
val res = parallelRuns(tableCollection)
Await.result(res, 3000000 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
res.value

////cmd 5
///this part set up functions and class for running cdm notebooks in parallel
/// the next two functions are for retry purpose. if running a process fail, it will retry
def tryNotebookRun (path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String]): Try[Any] = {
  Try(
    if (parameters.nonEmpty){
      dbutils.notebook.run(path, timeout, parameters)
    }
    else{
      dbutils.notebook.run(path, timeout)
    }
  )
}
def runWithRetry(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String], maxRetries: Int = 3) = {
  var numRetries = 0
  while (numRetries < maxRetries){
    tryNotebookRun(path, timeout, parameters) match {
      case Success(_) => numRetries = maxRetries
      case Failure(_) => numRetries = numRetries + 1
    }
  }
}
case class NotebookData(path: String, timeout: Int, parameters: Map[String, String] = Map.empty[String, String])
def parallelNotebooks(notebooks: Seq[NotebookData]): Future[Seq[Any]] = {
  val numNotebooksInParallel = 5
  // If you create too many notebooks in parallel the driver may crash when you submit all of the jobs at once.
  // This code limits the number of parallel notebooks.
  implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numNotebooksInParallel))
  val ctx = dbutils.notebook.getContext()
  Future.sequence(
    notebooks.map { notebook =>
      Future {
        dbutils.notebook.setContext(ctx)
        runWithRetry(notebook.path, notebook.timeout, notebook.parameters)
      }
      .recover {
        case NonFatal(e) => s"ERROR: ${e.getMessage}"
      }
    }
  )
}

////cmd 6
//run notebooks in parallel
val notebooks = Seq(
  NotebookData("AUDAdverseEvents", 0, Map("client"->client)),
  NotebookData("AUDAllergies", 0, Map("client"->client))
)
val res = parallelNotebooks(notebooks)
Await.result(res, 3000000 seconds) // this is a blocking call.
res.value
```
````

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in `tryRun()/runWithRetry()`:

  - Naming is extremely poor. The function name should show what it does. "Run" what? The comment doesn't even help -- it just says "a process". What does it *do*?
  - There is no need to use a `Try/Success/Failure` construct as you are capturing neither the result of the process on success nor the exception on failure. You can just use [the standard `try/catch` keywords](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/try-catch-finally.html).
  - You don't specify the return type of `runWithRetry()` - what's your intention? How is the caller supposed to know if it succeeded or failed?
  - Why don't you use the `case class tableInfo` as a parameter to these? More importantly from an OO point of view, why aren't these methods defined inside the class?
- in `parallelRuns()`:

  - Why are you using (explicitly, in fact) a `MutableList`? The list is not mutated, and seems to have no need to be mutated.
  - Why are you explicitly defining the parallelism instead of just using `.par` to get a Parallel Collection?
  - What is the comment about "notebooks" referring to?
  - What is the `.recover {}` clause supposed to do? The `Future`, as written, can't fail.
- in cmd 4:

  - Please use `yield` inside the `for` to create a list, instead of building up the list item by item.
- in cmd 5:

  - Create a class that does the necessary steps, and then have two things that inherit from it, specializing as necessary.

Comment: hello, thank you for the comments.  I do have an updated version that is cleaner now. These are great tips